# How to store state of TimestampAssigner/WatermarkGenerator during Checkpoints?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a usecase where eventTime(in TimestampAssigner) of an element depends on the max eventTime seen till now and an attribute of the element.

```
public class NewTimestampAssigner implements TimestampAssigner<Model> {
  private static final Duration ALLOWED_DELAY = Duration.ofHours(12);
  private long highestEventTime = 0L;
  
  @Override
  public long extractTimestamp(Model element, long recordTimestamp) {
    long timestamp = element.getTimeMs();
    if (timestamp > (this.highestEventTime - ALLOWED_DELAY.toMillis())) {
      timestamp = Math.max(timestamp, this.highestEventTime);
      this.highestEventTime = timestamp;
    }
    return timestamp;
  }
}
```

I want to store the value of variable `highestEventTime` in a state otherwise everytime job restart/redeploy the value of this variable is lost and I fail to get 100% deterministic result.
I tried implementing CheckpointingFunction in the class(NewTimestampAssigner) but methods did not get invoked - seems like CheckpointingFunction only works on Functions(Process, Map, etc).

I would like to know how to store the value of `highestEventTime` in a state while checkpointing, so in case of a restart - the NewTimestampAssigner starts from the same value ?

I tried implementing CheckpointingFunction in the class(NewTimestampAssigner) but methods(snapshotState, initializeState) did not get invoked - seems like CheckpointingFunction only works on Functions(Process, Map, etc).
I also tried implementing CheckpointingFunction in *Custom*`WatermarkStrategy` but methods(snapshotState, initializeState) did not invoke.

Comment: Note that because watermarks are periodically generated based on system time, you're mixing processing time & event time, so your workflow is already non-deterministic. So not sure how much effort you'd want to put into this (I don't know of an easy solution).

Answer (score 1):

I share Ken Krugler's skepticism about this being worth the trouble. Making watermarking fully deterministic is highly impractical, and will need more than this. But if you want to checkpoint the watermarks, I think the following should work:

- Do the watermarking in a custom operator.
- Implement CheckpointedFunction in that operator, and keep the state in union state, on a per-key-group basis (to allow for rescaling).

To learn how to implement a custom operator, see [Becoming a Smooth Operator: A look at low-level Flink APIs and what they enable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhaVG3kKj2E).